# Quick regex_search/replace, or clear indication of replacement?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, replace

I must browse a collection of strings to replace a pattern and save the changes.
The saving operation is (very) expensive and out of my hands, so I would like to know beforehand if the replacement did anything.

I can use `std::regex_search` to gain knowledge on the pattern's presence in my input, and use capture groups to store details in a `std::smatch`. `std::regex_replace` does not seem to explicitely tell me wether it did anything.

The patterns and strings are arbitrarily long and complicated; running `regex_replace` after a `regex_search` seems wasteful.
I can directly compare the input and output to search for a discrepancy but that too is uncomfortable.

Is there either a simple way to observe `regex_replace` to determine its impact, or to use a `smatch` filled by the `regex_search` to do a faster replacement operation ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long are the strings? And is the replacement of the same length or different lengths?

Comment: @rustyx Most will be under 256 charactes, but they can be arbitrarily long. The replacement is arbitrary and I cannot guarantee the length will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `regex_replace` doesn't provide this info and yes you can do it with a `regex_search` loop.

For example like this:

```
std::regex pattern("...");
std::string replacement_format = "...";
std::string input = "......"; // a very, very long string
std::string output, replacement;

std::smatch match;
auto begin = input.cbegin();
int replacements = 0;
while (std::regex_search(begin, input.cend(), match, pattern)) {
    output += match.prefix();
    replacement = match.format(replacement_format);
    if (match[0] != replacement) {
        replacements++;
    }
    output += replacement;
    begin = match.suffix().first;
}
output.append(begin, input.cend());

if (replacements > 0) {
    // process output ...
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mc1tZLpQvwRzpaS4)

Answer (score 0):

As `regex_replace` creates a copy of your string you could simply compare the replaced string with the original one and only "store" the new one if they differ.

For C++14 it seems that `regex_replace` returns a pointer to the last place it has written to:

> https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/ Versions 5
> and 6 return an iterator that points to the element past the last
> character written to the sequence pointed by out.

Comment: The strings can be very long, so comparison is a backup solution. I unfortunately am stuck with C++11. It also points to the end of the output, but this does not mean the output is any different from the input.

Comment: Depending on the replace you could rely on a changed size of the string, which will be a fast comparison.